# Understanding scipy integrate's internal behavior

Tags: python, scipy, ode, numerical-integration

I am trying to understand what `scipy.integrate` is doing internally. Namely, it seems that something weird and inconsistent is happening.

**How get it working properly? I need it to perform one integration step at a time, because I do some stuff with `t` inside the ODE and need it to be consistent**

So, here is my MWE

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import ode

t0 = 0
t1 = 1

def myODE(t, x):
    print('INTERNAL t = {time:2.3f}'.format(time=t))

    Dx = np.zeros([2, 1])
    Dx[0] = -x[0]**2
    Dx[1] = -x[1]**2

    return Dx

simulator = ode(myODE).set_integrator('dopri5')
simulator.set_initial_value(np.ones([2,1]), t0)

t = simulator.t

while t < t1:
    t = simulator.t
    print('Outside integrate t = {time:2.3f}'.format(time=t))
    x = simulator.integrate(2, step=True) 

    print('x1 = {x1:2.3f}'.format(x1=x[0,0]))
```

What I'm trying to do to perform one integration step at a time. Instead, `integrate` does something else. As you can see from the output below, it performs several steps at a time, and those steps are inconsistent: sometimes, `t` increases and the decreases again.

```
Outside integrate t = 0.000
INTERNAL t = 0.000
INTERNAL t = 0.010
INTERNAL t = 0.004
INTERNAL t = 0.006
INTERNAL t = 0.016
...
INTERNAL t = 1.969
INTERNAL t = 1.983
INTERNAL t = 2.000
INTERNAL t = 2.000
x1 = 0.333
Outside integrate t = 2.000
INTERNAL t = 2.000
...
INTERNAL t = 2.000
x1 = 0.333
```

Comment: It's normal for `ode` solvers to use variable time steps.  Depending on the particular solver it may evaluate several times close together to get a numeric `jacobian` (derivative).  It may also use fine steps when the function changes fast, and longer ones when it changes slower.  The goal is to minimize the total number of evaluations while maintaining accuracy.  The docs give a journal reference.

Comment: Look at `odeint`.  It lets you specify an array to `t` points.

Comment: You can give the `nsteps=1` parameter for the `dopri5` solver. However this still results in 2 steps taken. Note that dopri5 has 6+1 ODE function evaluations per step, one can reuse the last evaluation of a step as it is the same as the first of the next step.

Comment: Whatever you want to do with the ODE, it almost certainly should not depend on the interna of the method used and its step size controller. Use events and dense output options, and if possible, the actively developed interface `solve_ivp`.

Comment: @LutzLehmann 1solve_ivp` doesn't allow you to perform a single step at a time and store intermediate data. Say, `RK45` is a class which is far more superior in my view.
The problem is that `events` is not appropriate in my case: I need to buffer the `t` variable inside of RHS

Comment: Yes, using the underlying stepper classes directly will allow for more fine control. Could you describe more closely what you mean with "buffer the `t` variable inside of RHS" and also check if your equation falls into the category of delay-differential equations, DDE?

Comment: @LutzLehmann It means I mimic sorta zero-order hold behavior which needs information about the current `t`. Yes, it falls into that category.
Well, I did get it working seemingly correct, while the explanation is simply, as pointed out above, the solver calls the RHS multiple times per step

Comment: For a zero order hold, you can also use scipy.interpolate.interp1d, kind="zero", see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60223218/3088138, second variant.

Comment: (To clarify, that one can not get single steps in `ode/dopri5` is an implementation error there. But as that is the obsolete version, a correction is not to be expected. Using the stepper classes underlying the "more functional" interface `solve_ivp` like `RK45` should give the same or more functionality as the `ode` class. Using `solve_ivp` should lead in most cases that are proper ODE problems to shorter code that is more easily adaptable, using the stepper class can be more flexible.)

Comment: @LutzLehmann To summarize, this is what I used -- the pythonic class colustion, which is the closest to my needs. `interp1d` is not suitable for real-time use. I hard-coded ZOH. Again, it seems to work in hope that the solver taking more "virtual" steps for one actual step is not a big deal. I'd highlight it in the documentation though

Answer (score 1):

All solvers that are better than the standard fixed-step RK4 method use a variable step size. Treating the solver as a black-box, one can not know what internal step sizes are used.

What is known, however, is that the explicit one-step methods have multiple stages, at least equal to their order, that each comprise a call to the ODE function at a point close to, but not necessarily on the solution trajectory. Implicit methods may have less stages than the order, but require an iterative approach to the solution of the implicit step equations.

The Dormand-Prince 45 method has 7 stages, where the last stage is also the first of the next step, so in the long-time average 6 evaluations per step. This is what you see in the `ode(dopri)` method.

```
INTERNAL t =   0.00000000
INTERNAL t =   0.01000000
INTERNAL t =   0.00408467
INTERNAL t =   0.00612700
INTERNAL t =   0.01633866
INTERNAL t =   0.01815407
INTERNAL t =   0.02042333
INTERNAL t =   0.02042333
INTERNAL t =   0.03516563
INTERNAL t =   0.04253677
INTERNAL t =   0.07939252
INTERNAL t =   0.08594465
INTERNAL t =   0.09413482
INTERNAL t =   0.09413482
Outside integrate t =   0.09413482
...
```

There one can see that the minimal step of the scipy method consists of 2 DoPri steps. In the sequence of the first step, the first evaluation is just probing if the initial step size is appropriate, this is only done once. All the other step points are at the prescribed times `t_n+c_i*dt` where `c=[0,1/5,3/10,4/5,8/9,1,1]`.

You can get proper single steps with the new classes that are the steppers for the new interface `solve_ivp`. Take care that the default tolerances are here much looser than in the `ode(dopri)` case, probably following the Matlab philosophy of generating "good enough" plots with minimal effort. For `RK45` this can look like

```python
simulator = RK45(myODE, t0, [1,1], t1, atol=6.8e-7, rtol=2.5e-8)

t = simulator.t

while t < t1:
    simulator.step() 
    t = simulator.t
    x = simulator.y
    print(f'Outside integrate t = {t:12.8f}')
    print(f'x1 = {x[0]:12.10f}, err = {x[0]-1/(1+t):8.6g}')
```

This uses slightly different internal steps, but, as said, has a "true" single-step output.

```
INTERNAL t =   0.00000000
INTERNAL t =   0.01000000
INTERNAL t =   0.00408223
INTERNAL t =   0.00612334
INTERNAL t =   0.01632891
INTERNAL t =   0.01814323
INTERNAL t =   0.02041114
INTERNAL t =   0.02041114
Outside integrate t =   0.02041114
x1 = 0.9799971436, err = 5.2347e-13
INTERNAL t =   0.04750541
INTERNAL t =   0.06105254
INTERNAL t =   0.12878821
INTERNAL t =   0.14083011
INTERNAL t =   0.15588248
INTERNAL t =   0.15588248
Outside integrate t =   0.15588248
x1 = 0.8651399668, err = 1.13971e-07
...
```

If you have an input that is a step function, or a zero-order hold, the most expedient solution would be to loop over the steps and initialize one `RK45` object per step with the step segment as integration boundaries. Save the last value as initial value for the next step. Perhaps also the last step size as initial step size in the next step.

Directly using a step function inside the ODE function is inefficient, as the step size controller expects a very smooth ODE function for an optimal step size sequence. At jumps that is grossly violated and can lead to stark local reductions in the step size, and accordingly an increased number of function evaluations.