# Does SciPy RK45 (solve_ivp) count the number of function evaluations accurately?

Tags: python, scipy, runge-kutta, ode45

I want to measure the performance of my own ODE integrator against SciPy [RK45](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.RK45.html#scipy.integrate.RK45). Thus, I need to know exactly the number of right hand side function evaluations that RK45 uses.

Does anyone know if the number sol.nfev is accurate, i.e. without repititions? For example, if RK45 rejects a step size and repeats the step, is the initial evaluation f(t,x) of the step counted multiple times?
Also, the [Dormand-Prince RK method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dormand%E2%80%93Prince_method) used by RK45 has 7 stages, but in reality only uses 6 evaluations per step because of the "First Same As Last" property (the last stage is evaluated at the same point as the first stage of the next step). Is that accounted for in sol.nfev?

Comment: You can create a list outside your right-hand side function and append all evaluated t to it. After integration you can check if that list has the same length as set(list).

Comment: In my sporadic tests of it, I never encountered a failed step. I'm not sure if a failed-step mechanism is even included in the code references of Shampine or Hairer. // There is a single additional Euler step performed in the first step, presumably to compute a sensible initial step size. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62343906/understanding-scipy-integrates-internal-behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experiments I can confirm that RK45 counts accurately, i.e. repititions are not evaluated and not counted. For anyone wondering how the number sol.nfev can be explained: 
Denote the number of RK steps reported by RK45 as `num_steps = len(sol.t) - 1` and the number of rejected steps by `num_rej`. Then it holds

```
sol.nfev = (num_steps + num_rej) * 6 + 2
```

as every step needs 6 function evaluations, except the first one, which needs 7. Additionaly, there is one Euler step in the beginning to generate an initial step size (ergo the `+2`). Thanks @LutzLehmann for pointing that out.

Here is an example:

```
class Fun:
def __init__(self):
    self.t = []
    self.x = []

def __call__(self, t, x):
    self.t.append(t)
    self.x.append(x)
    if t <= 1:
        return - x ** 2
    return 10  # discontinuity to provoke step rejection

t0 = 0
t1 = 1.01
x0 = [1]
sol = solve_ivp(Fun(), (t0, t1), x0)

print(sol.nfev)
print(len(f.t))
num_steps = len(sol.t) - 1
print(num_steps)
print(num_steps * 6 + 2)
```

From the output

```
56
56
7
44
```

we can see that there are 7 RK steps in the final solution `sol` but because of the discontinuity in the function, there also were 2 rejected steps (44 + 2 * 6 = 56).